# nginx server location for single page

Tags: nginx

I just want to set a location for a single page:

```
/showthread.php?t=2589&page=3
```

(and other pages 1,2 as well)

I'm writing in the config:

```
location ~* ^.+showthread\.php\?t=2589.+$ {
```

This online tester says that the string matches: http://regexr.com?30bk3
But actually it does not. WTF? Does nginx use "special" regexp or what? How to make the right expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tilde:

```
location ~ ^.+showthread.php\?t=2589.+$
```

to indicate a regex, otherwise nginx treats it as literal.

Update:

I'm sorry, I was reading too quickly, and focused on your typo instead of the query string.

So, the trick is that "location" matches on the location, which is /showthread.php.  The rest of your query string are GET parameters and won't be in the thing that you're trying to pattern match.

Take a look at the documentation:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24args

So, you'd need something like:

```
location /showthread.php {
  if ($arg_t = '2589') {
     # do some stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried, but it doesn't work. What do you mean with "otherwise nginx treats it as literal." ? Official docs say that “~*” is for case-insensitive regex,  “~” for sensitive

Comment: Awww! Just saw it: I mistaked in my question. There WAS "~*" (just edited) but still doesn't work.

Comment: @ABTOMAT, Please check my update

Comment: Thanks for update. I tried if directive, but now it says "proxy_ignore_headers" directive is not allowed here in (if condition), i use "proxy_ignore_headers" inside the if body (# do some stuff). That's strange that I can do something beyound "if" but can't inside... Anyway even this doesn't help

Comment: Oh, yes.  There's a bunch of stuff that doesn't work in an "if" block. Can you post the actual thing you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm actually trying to cache these pages for everyone: http://pastebin.com/B2YY7wZ9 (sorry for pastebin link, but it's hard to write code in comments). And this cache conf does work unless i'm trying to connect it only to t=2589

Comment: I don't have any good ideas.  Maybe you can put a rewrite inside the "if" that goes to a location like "/showthread/2589/", and then use a location block that does your proxy directives?  nginx can be frustrating at times.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx locations only match the URI stem, and not the parameters passed in (the stuff after the question mark).

So your location is going to need to be something simple like

```
  location /showthread.php {/*some stuff*/}
```

If you want different nginx behavior depending on the value of parameters, you will likely have to use an if block *inside* that location with a regex on the parameters to rewrite/redirect or do whatever else you need.

If you control showthread.php, it's probably best to add this complexity there rather than in your nginx configuration.

See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more information.